# Sort a 3D array using 1D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have two numpy arrays:

```
lst = np.array([8, 1, 6, 9, 2])

arr = np.array([[[  6, 455],
    [  8, 106],
    [  1, 953],
    [  2, 725],
    [  9, 427]],

   [[  2, 427],
    [  8, 953],
    [  1, 106],
    [  9, 455],
    [  6, 725]]])
```

Note that `arr[0,:,0]` and `arr[1,:,0]` are both permutations of `lst`.

I want to sort `arr` such that both `arr[0,:,0]` and `arr[1,:,0]` are in the same order as `lst` (and the rows are correctly sorted). In other words, I want the following outcome:

```
ans = np.array([[[  8, 106],
        [  1, 953],
        [  6, 455],
        [  9, 427],
        [  2, 725]],
       [[  8, 953],
        [  1, 106],
        [  6, 725],
        [  9, 455],
        [  2, 427]]])
```

I can get my desired outcome using list comprehension, but I'm looking for a more efficient solution. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the indexes then pick accordingly

```py
# for arr[0,:,0]

mapping = dict(zip(arr[0,:,0], np.arange(arr[0,:,0].shape[0])))

vfunc = np.vectorize(mapping.__getitem__)
new_index = vfunc(lst)

print(arr[0, new_index, :])

# array([[  8, 106],
#        [  1, 953],
#        [  6, 455],
#        [  9, 427],
#        [  2, 725]])
```

Comment: So do you wrap this with a loop (for the other subarrays)? Is there a built-in numpy method that deals with this in one go?

Comment: You can try `np. vectorize` but it is essential for loop under the hood but gives a clear syntax. If speed is not concened.